# How to securely distinguish traffic from my app and browser traffic

Tags: security, mobile

I'm designing a game that makes queries to a database on the web. The database is fronted by a web service. For example, a request could look like this:

```
Endpoint: "server.com/user/UID/buygold"
POST:
    amount: 100
```

The web service would make sure that userid has enough funds to purchase 100 gold, then would return a Boolean answer based on the success of the transaction.

However, I want to limit the amount of scripting someone could possibly do to automate gameplay. For example, they could figure out their userid and have automated tasks that buy gold for them while they are at work.

On the web services side, what are some sound security measures that I can put in place to decline all but real app traffic. Is there also a way to trump reverse engineers who will take the app apart and look for keys/certs?

Comment: Do this on the server, not the client. How about https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof-of-work_system

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan, I'm not sure what you mean. The user would click the "buy gold" button in-game and an API request would be made to the game server which would validate the purchase or not. I'm not sure how I can allow that to happen on the client itself.

Comment: "I want to limit the amount of scripting someone could possibly do to automate"

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan, ahhh got it thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that this is not for a production environment, the security implications alone are mind boggling and certainly go beyond the scope of the allowed response, as it would require a rather lengthy and in depth list of requirements and recommendations, that are really contingent on many other factors that make up your web-service environment. For example, the network topology, authentication, session control and management, and various other variables all play important roles in fostering and implementing a sound cyber security counter measure.

However, assuming that you have all that taken care of, I will answer your main questions as follows:

**For question:**

> "what are some sound security measures that I can put in place to decline all but real app traffic"

**Answer:**

This is one of many options out there that would address your particular concern, and that is to check for the client User-Agent header in the the request, which may appear something like this:

> **"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 32.11; rv:49.0) Gecko/20122101 Firefox/42.0"**

Depending on how the script is being run to automate gameplay, if it is in the form of a browser extension, then the User Agent really plays very poorly as a counter measure, if on the other hand, the script is being run directly from the client to your server (web-service), then, you can detect it right away, and there are ways to detect if someone spoofed a User Agent just to bypass this counter measure.

Another counter measure you can utilize is session management at the client level. So, this would require an architectural overview of how you implemented your particular project, but a general summary would follow a pattern like this:

- Customer/GamePlayer would naturally be required to login (authentication of some sort)
- The client system (which is the User Interface) that the game player is using, will have counter measures implemented in a front-end type of scripting language, i.e. Javascript or any framework that makes use of JS, such as jQuery, DoJo, etc.
- Register event handlers that monitor actions, such as type of input, some Boolean logic that will follow something like this:
  **"if input is not from keyboard or mouse, then send flag with request"**
  The server/web-service will have logic to handle this request appropriately. This would be a way to catch/detect the game player after they commit the violation, used for legal reasons and such to profile evidence and such. If on the other hand you want to prevent that from happening, then, you could have some Boolean logic that goes something like this: **"if input is not from the keyboard or mouse (or whatever permitted input device), then do not allow action (GamePlay), and still report back to web-server"**.

There are a dozen other ways, but this one seems to generally address your question, provided that you take into consideration that there are hundreds of other factors to think about, from networking level all the way to the application layer, and down to what pattern are you using for your web-service, such as whether it's a REST/API type of environment, does it follow an MVC pattern, and so on.  There is no silver lining  when it comes to cyber security, it's really a proactive and constant initiative on your end to ensure that all stakeholders' assets are protected, in this case, the asset is the web-service and gameplay, and the threat is the risk of gameplay tampering, that would affect the integrity of your game.

**Now, regarding your second question:**

> " Is there also a way to trump reverse engineers who will take the app apart and look for keys/certs?"

When reverse engineers really put their mind to it, there is nothing you can really do, as whatever counter measure you may implement, they will find a workaround, that's why it's called reverse engineering, they will reverse engineer your "counter measure", so, not to be all cynical about it, you have to accept the reality that there is really no such thing as a "trump" counter measure when it comes to cyber security. You can however employ various mechanisms at both, the network layer and all the way to the application level, combined with proactive initiatives, intrusion detection, abnormal behavioral characteristics of the gameplay pattern, all will mitigate your risk; with all that said, your final frontier will be to ensure you have a good legal policy in place in your TOS (terms of service), and depending where you're hosting your web-service (geographically), you will be protected when users violate such terms, especially when you have verbiage that precludes users from attempting to reverse-engineer, tamper with gameplay scoreboards or currency, and so on.

Another good way, is to really connect with users, users are people, and people sometimes forget that they are also affecting others by their actions, so, once a user is aware of how his/her actions may negatively affect others, such as in the case of a user's actions to increase their 100 Gold, they may financially and emotionally affect others who may have put real time and effort into making this service even possible, so, a simple introductory welcome video upon signing up can do wonders for example; however, sometimes the user may not really know that they were prohibited from using auto-scripts for gameplay, or at least can raise an affirmative defense of that, so, having well published policies can really mitigate and potentially reduce altogether these types of risks.  Despite the potentially optimistic outlook on users, you still have to exercise good programming practices and have security counter measures in place though.

I hope that I have given you some insight and direction to assist you with this matter, and that as you can see, it is really an involved and can be a very complicated type of process.

Good luck with your initiatives.

Comment: Thanks for the great response! However, your opening paragraph makes it seem like you would implement this another way. How else can you allow players to "purchase" a good or increase their points without sending that information to a central server over the wire? How else would a game allow players to "buy gold"?

Comment: The way I would implement this is based on a host of other variables as I've mentioned in my response. This is not a question that can be answered on stack overflow for various obvious reasons, such as having a solution on how you would prevent users from tampering your system defeats the whole purpose as it will be published on here. It would make it easy to reverse engineer your counter-measure when malicious users know what the counter measure is, or at the very least, the bulk of what the counter measure is. Continued in next thread:

Comment: Continued from previous comment:

I would imagine that the general recommendations I provided in my response should pave the way to a sound and good countermeasure.   I also suggest consulting with a certified cyber-security professional to assist, perhaps engage in a pen-testing with limited scope that addresses your concerns. If budget does not permit you to hire a certified cyber security professional for their services, you can at least perhaps find a professional that would be willing to give you free consultation, and make recommendations as needed.